# Formatting List of String

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array of strings. I need to sort the list and save each letter's item in a single line.  After this, I need to find the longest line of string.

I have done the first part in an inefficient way but I am trying to make it concise.

```
List<string> fruits = new List<string>
               {
                "Pomme",
                "Apple",
                "Apricots",
                "Avocado",
                "Banana",
                "Blackberries",
                "Blackcurrant",
                "Blueberries",
                "Cherries",
                "Clementine",
                "Cranberries",
                "Custard-Apple",
                "Durian",
                "Elderberries",
                "Feijoa",
                "Figs",
                "Gooseberries",
                "Grapefruit",
                "Grapes",
                "Guava",
                "Breadfruit",
                "Cantaloupe",
                "Carambola",
                "Cherimoya",
                };
    
                fruits.Sort();
    
                List<string> sortedString = new List<string> { };
    
                foreach (var str in fruits)
                {
                    sortedString.Add(str);
                }
    
                //string A, B, C, D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S; 
                var A = "";
                var B = "";
                var C = "";
                var D = "";
                var E = "";
                var F = "";
                var G = "";
                
                foreach (var item in sortedString)
                {
                    if (item.StartsWith('A'))
                    {
                        A += item;
                    }
                    else if (item.StartsWith('B'))
                    {
                        B += item;
                    }
                    else if (item.StartsWith('C'))
                    {
                        C += item;
                    }
                    else if (item.StartsWith('D'))
                    {
                        D += item;
                    }
                    else if (item.StartsWith('E'))
                    {
                        E += item;
                    }
                    else if (item.StartsWith('F'))
                    {
                        F += item;
                    }
                    
                }
```

The result will be like -

```
AppleApricotsAvocado
BananaBlackberriesBlackcurrantBlueberriesBreadfruit
CantaloupeCarambolaCherimoyaCherriesClementineCranberriesCustard-Apple
Durian
Elderberries
FeijoaFigs
GooseberriesGrapefruitGrapesGuava
```

After this, I need to find the longest line and put space between each item. Without effective looping, the code will be messy. Can you assist me to show the right way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `Sort()` method already sorts your list and you don't need to assign it to a new one.

My proposal to resolve your problem is

```
fruits.Sort();
var result = fruits.GroupBy(f => f[0]);
int[] lineslength = new int[result.Count()];
int index = 0;
foreach (var group in result)
{
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        lineslength[index] += item.Length;
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    index++;
}
int longestIndex = Array.FindIndex(lineslength, val => val.Equals(lineslength.Max()));
Console.WriteLine(longestIndex);
```

I used the GroupBy method to group strings by their first letter. Then when I was displaying strings I also counted their length. Using the static FindIndex method of the Array class, I found the index containing the maximum value of the array what corresponds to the line with the maximum length. So index zero is the first line, one is the second line etc.